# ReflectionException Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I have developed an application with Laravel, version 5.1, using homestead to test.

When I place it on the production server, I get this error that I can't replicate on the local machine:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 736
Class MyMultiSelect does not exist
```

This class is a sleeping-owl Custom Form Item
http://sleeping-owl.github.io/en/Form_Elements/Custom_Form_Elements.html

I checked for:

- namespace errors / conflicts
- I even placed the class in the global namespace
- tried to load the file containing the class in `composer.json`

**Filename**: `MyMultiSelect.php`

**Class**: `MyMultiSelect`

**namespace:** Global so to access it `\MyMultiSelect`

```
admin/bootstrap.php
```

`FormItem::register('myMultiSelect', \MyMultiSelect::class);`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where did you put your MyMultiselect class? Are you sure it is in global namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run **composer dump-autoload** on your server. This will rebuild the autoloader cache, that stores paths to classes. If your paths are different locally and on the server, this could help.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem! More simple than i imagined